# Registered Plugin on Retrieve of Entity facing an Error "Unauthorized Error"

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I registered a plugin on Retrieve of Entity.
but when I open record shows "Unauthorized User Error".
I want to to decode some field values.
I also used Trace log but shows nothing, Shows Same Error

Answer (score 0):

When you have error in code and you registered a plugin on Retrieve of Entity, it shows the "Unauthorized User Error".
Or When you want to Throw Exception in that Plugin means on Retrieve of Entity, it will also shows same Error.
and there is no trace log means you can't trace it. 
I registered the Plugin on Retrieve on Pre-Operation of Entity.

I solved the Error, and handle the exceptions.
and then update the Plugin, it is working fine.

On Retrieve you can't Trace plugin, and when you want to throw exception or there is error in your code it will shows Error when you open the record the error is "Unauthorized User Error".